# Redirect ls using execl

Tags: c, unix

I'd like to use ls from execl and redirect the output to a file, which exists. I tried with this:

`int value = execl("/bin/ls","ls","-l",">/home/sbam/myfile",NULL);`

But it doesn't work... How can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a shell as `/bin/ls` is not one and therefore does not understand redirection

Comment: If I try from terminal (Xubuntu) `ls -l > myfile`, then I found the output of ls -l in myfile. I'd like to do that with execl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection is part of the shell and not something the commands handles. Either invoke a shell and execute the command through the shell, or you could open the file using [`open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and use [`dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) to make the file the process standard output.

Something like

```
int fd = open("/home/sbam/myfile", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
if (fd != -1)
{
    if (dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) != -1)
    {
        if (execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", NULL) == -1)
            perror("execl");
    }
    else
        perror("dup2");
}
else
    perror("open");
```

Comment: Although omitting error checking is often an acceptable abbreviation in sample code, I think it's pretty important here to verify that open succeeds.  The exec should not happen if the open fails.